# Running curl via powershell - how to construct arguments?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to run curl to upload a file in my script, using batch was painful because I need to do string manipulation etc so I turned to powershell.

However I can't seem to get powershell to execute Curl:

```
$hash = "test"
$fileToUpload = "hello world.txt"
$user = "user"
$password = "passy"
curl --ftp-create-dirs -T $fileToUpload -u ${user}:${pass} ftp://example.com/$hash/$fileToUpload
```

This results in:

```
Invoke-WebRequest : Parameter cannot be processed because the parameter name 'T' is ambiguous. Possible matches include: 
-TimeoutSec -TransferEncoding.
At line:5 char:24
+ curl --ftp-create-dirs -T $fileToUpload -u ${user}:${pass} ftp://example.com/$ha ...
+                        ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameter,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

Curl.exe is in my PATH.

Comment: `curl` -> `curl.exe`

Comment: huh.. why does that work?

Comment: To add to what @PetSerAl said - when calling "curl", it is mapped as an alias to the Invoike-WebRequest cmdlet. Use "curl.exe" to call the curl executable. You can confirm this with: Get-Alias -name curl

Comment: Ah I didn't know it was a built in thing, if someone adds an answer I'll accept

Comment: @PetSerAl should get the accepted answer.

Comment: He will if he adds an actual answer :)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

In PowerShell `curl` is a built in alias to `Invoke-WebRequest` cmdlet. And aliases have priority in command resolution. To solve your problem you have more specifically, use `curl.exe` instead of `curl`, so command not resolved to alias. Or you can remove alias `Remove-Item alias:curl`, but as it is build in alias you have to put this command in your profile, or invoke it in every session.

If you are not sure how PowerShell resolve your command, then you can use `Get-Command` cmdlet:

```
Get-Command curl
Get-Command curl.exe
```

Comment: You can also check if an alias exists for a given command name by running `Get-Alias -Name yourcommand`.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers You mean `-Definition`? `Get-Alias -Definition Invoke-WebRequest`

Comment: I meant `-Name`: `Get-Alias -Name curl`. I probably should've said "to check if for a given command name an alias with the same name exists".

Comment: Thank you...In my case using curl.exe instead of curl, solved the problem.

Comment: correct answer! thanks. .exe extension such a annoying thing when using powershell.

Comment: For me, I need to use `curl.exe`... because of a `-sL` parameter will not work. `curl -sL https://aws-amplify.github.io/amp...`