# Convert Gitlab CI Trigger Curl to Powershell Invoke-RestMethod

Tags: powershell, curl, gitlab

Does anyone know if it's possible to convert the `curl` command used to trigger builds in Gitlab-CI to a Powershell equivalent using `Invoke-RestMethod`?

Example `curl` command:

```
curl --request POST \
  --form token=TOKEN \
  --form ref=master \
  --form "variables[UPLOAD_TO_S3]=true" \
  https://gitlab.example.com/api/v3/projects/9/trigger/builds
```

This was taken from Gitlab's [documentation](http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/triggers/README.html) page.

I found quite a few postings about converting a `curl` script for Powershell but I haven't had any luck in getting it to work. Here are some of the links I referenced:

- [How to send multipart/form-data with PowerShell Invoke-RestMethod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22491129/how-to-send-multipart-form-data-with-powershell-invoke-restmethod)
- [PowerShell equivalent of curl](https://superuser.com/questions/344927/powershell-equivalent-of-curl)
- [Running curl via powershell - how to construct arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30807318/running-curl-via-powershell-how-to-construct-arguments)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can pass the token and the branch parameters directly in the URL. As for variables, putting it into the body variable should do the trick.

```
$Body = @{
    "variables[UPLOAD_TO_S3]" = "true"
}

Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v3/projects/9/trigger/builds?token=$Token&ref=$Ref" -Body $Body
```

Comment: Life safer! That did the trick.  I didn't think about attaching the tokens directly within the URL.  Thanx!

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can pass all arguments in the body parameter:

```powershell
$form = @{token = $CI_JOB_TOKEN;ref = $BRANCH_TO_BUILD; "variables[SERVER_IMAGE_TAG]" = $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}
Invoke-WebRequest -Method POST -Body $form -Uri https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/602/trigger/pipeline -UseBasicParsing
```