# cURL not recognizing command line parameters (Windows 10)

Tags: windows, curl

Not sure what I'm doing wrong, but any command line parameters I try to pass into curl (using double dash) are interpreted as a url.
Running `curl --help`:

```
curl : The remote name could not be resolved: '--help'
At line:1 char:1
+ curl --help
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebExc
   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

With a single dash it seems to interpret a url parameter, but it doesn't find certain parameters. Running `curl -sSL`:

```
Invoke-WebRequest : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'sSL'.
At line:1 char:6
+ curl -sSL
+      ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

Curl binary downloaded from https://curl.se/windows/

Answer (score 3):

You can find the answer here: [Running curl via powershell - how to construct arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30807318/running-curl-via-powershell-how-to-construct-arguments)

"In PowerShell curl is a built in alias to Invoke-WebRequest cmdlet. And aliases have priority in command resolution. To solve your problem you have more specifically, use curl.exe instead of curl, so command not resolved to alias"