# While I try to add docker desktop kubernetes to rancher cluster it shows error in curl command which they provided in adding cluster in rancher

Tags: kubernetes, rancher, docker-desktop

```
curl --insecure -sfL https://104.211.32.151:8443/v3/import/zp2b5dhb7h79fn7qlk2g7k4rl2mv7b2j29s8brxfzmhskfnt4tvpmd.yaml | kubectl apply -f -
Invoke-WebRequest : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'sfL'.
At line:1 char:17
+ curl --insecure -sfL https://104.211.32.151:8443/v3/import/zp2b5dhb7h ...
+                 ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your shell.

I usually use `c:\Program files\Git\mingw64\bin\curl.exe` (shipped with [Git for windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases)) or `C:\Windows\System32\curl.exe` (with [Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50200838/6309)), in a regular CMD shell session.

But if you are using a Powershell, as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30807818/6309), `curl` is a built in alias to Invoke-WebRequest cmdlet.

Use `curl.exe` instead of `curl`.

Comment: I don't know why, but I tried this command after some time and resolved my error! Thanks for sharing your solution!