# Getting New Access Token in VBA - translating PowerShell curl.exe command

Tags: excel, vba, powershell, curl

I run the following command in PowerShell:

```
curl.exe -X POST https://app.inventorum.com/api/auth/token/ -u '$CLIENTID:$CLIENTSECRET' -d 'grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=$REFRESHTOKEN'
```

It returns a valid new refresh and bearer token.

How can this be done in VBA in Excel?

```vb
Private Function getAccessToken() As String
Dim httpRequest As New WinHttpRequest
Dim apiUrl As String

apiUrl = "https://app.inventorum.com/api/auth/token/"

httpRequest.Open "POST", apiUrl
httpRequest.SetCredentials clientId, clientSecret, 0
httpRequest.send "grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=" & refreshToken

Debug.Print httpRequest.responseText
End Function
```

The returned response:

> {"error": "unsupported_grant_type"}

Comment: Why is this tagged PowerShell, when your specific use case is VBA execution? Even the Command you are using is not PS, as you are using ```curl.exe``` (a cmd.exe executable, thus cmd.exe is handling this call) directly and not ```curl``` (aka Invoke-WebRequest). So, you are looking for help with VBA, not PS in any way. [What did you search for](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27msexcel+getaccesstoken%27&t=ffab&ia=web)?

Comment: First of all, the PowerShell implementation of `curl` is accessible under curl.exe as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30807818/1626443. Second, it's a "translation problem" because several methods produce different results and PowerShell provides me with the correct result and thus I included it.

Comment: https://success.qualys.com/discussions/s/question/0D52L00004TnxOUSAZ/curl-api-call-in-vba

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this.  This is a C# implementation.

```
using System.Net.Http.Headers;

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://app.inventorum.com/api/auth/token/");

request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("$CLIENTID:$CLIENTSECRET")));

request.Content = new StringContent("grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=$REFRESHTOKEN");
request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```